# How to validate ids between XML documents in XSD?

Tags: php, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm trying to make a cross platform string management system, for both iOS and Android app (so I don't have to translate both app and I reuse string from one app into the other).

For this, I use the following flow :

1. XML storing cross platform string *identifiers* (with potentially attributes like `comment` or `iOS-only`, ...)

   ```
   <!-- identifiers.xml -->
   <identifiers>
      <id>button_signin_facebook</id>
      <id ios-only="true">button_signin_apple</id>
      ...
   </identifiers>
   ```
2. And then I have N translations for the N supported languages :

   ```
   <!-- translation_en.xml -->
   <translation lang="en">
     <string id="button_signin_facebook">Continue with Facebook</string>
     <string id="button_signin_apple">Continue with Apple ID</string>
     ...
   </translation>
   ```

A PHP script processes all of this and generate all translation files for both platform, after verifying integrity (see if some string are unused, see if we have created a string twice etc.)

***Now my question is :
How to make a XSD for the `translation_lang.xml` files enforcing that the `id` attribute of `string` elements is a "enumeration" (or "reference" ?) from all the `id` in the `identifiers.xml` file ?*** (just like a foreign key in a database)

I'm new to XSD, and I found that I could make enumeration in XSD, but it's not what I want. (The identifiers values needs to be in the XML file identifiers.xml and not in a schema, because they are not fixed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSD cannot express constraints between separate XML documents.

Alternative possibilities:

1. Write the cross-document validation constraints in XSLT, PHP, or another language.
2. Combine the separate XML documents into a single composite XML document for purposes of validating via XSD.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I verify all of this with PHP before the generation of platform string files, but XSD validation is really helpful for IDE auto completion. If I use solution 2, how can I express the foreign key within the single file ?

Comment: Once the identifiers and references are in a single file,  you can use `xsd:key` and `xsd:keyref` to validate such referential integrity constraints.  For example, see [Allow only other existing XML values in XSD? (xs:key and xs:keyref)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51537997/290085).

Comment: Thank you I'll check it out :)

Comment: Another possibility for cross-document validation is to use XSD 1.1 assertions. Technically, the XPath assertions used in a schema can't reference external documents using the doc() function, but you may find that not all processors impose this restriction.